# Wordpress get_the_content() returns <!-- wp:paragraph --> markup

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created a new custom post type and created a few sample posts in the Guttenberg editor. However when I try to echo this content out to a textarea, to allow users to edit, it displays it as html markup:

```
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>This is a test custom post content</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p></p>
```

I am using the following code to output this

```
<textarea><?php echo esc_attr(get_the_content()); ?></textarea>
```

I'm assuming this is something to do with Guttenbergs blocks as it does not do this on posts with the classic editor. I'm a relative beginner to wordpress development so apologies if there is a simple function that deals with this but I can't seem to find oue.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this:

```
<textarea><?php echo esc_attr(wp_strip_all_tags(get_the_content())); ?></textarea>
```

wp_strip_all_tags() will remove all these tags, and since this is just textarea, and not WYSIWIG editor, you only need plain text